# Control kodi from stdin

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, pi-3, kodi, qt

I wonder if it possible to send characters to the stdin of kodi (i.e. using Qt `QProcess::write()` to simulate a keyboard.

I did the same with other applications - like omxplayer - and it worked. But now it seems it doesn't. 
I'm using Raspbian Jessie Lite with RPi2 and RPi3, and this is the code that is supposed to send the "left arrow" keystroke:

```
QProcess *m_kodi = new QProcess(this);
m_kodi->start("kodi");
// ...
m_kodi->write("c"); // should open the Contextual menu
// ...
QByteArray left;
left.append(0x1B);
left.append('[');
left.append('D');
m_kodi->write(left); // should move the current focus to the left
```

Do you see any evidence of something wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with Kodi (although this is more of a gut feeling than anything I can give you a reference for). They've tightened up the remote control options a little in the last few years, mainly nudging everyone towards the [JSON-RPC API](http://kodi.wiki/view/JSON-RPC_API). I've made use of the API several times, and it works pretty well.

Comment: Yeah, I'll go for JSON-RPC API. Though having the "keyboard emulation" via stdin could be useful somtimes!